# Анимация Swing при первом запуске

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо, чтобы при первом запуске программы она отрисовывала график заданной функции с анимацией, а затем просто выводила его статично. Со вторым пунктом  и первым по отдельности проблем нет. Затрудняюсь заставить это работать вместе.
Отрисовка статичного графика с автомасштабированием под размеры окна ниже. Как сделать анимацию?

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


    for (double k = 0; k <= Main.L; k += 0.125) {
        g.drawOval((int) Math.round(k * usefullCoef) + STARTPOINTX, (int) Math.round((Main.frame.getContentPane().getHeight()) - Main.wayConstruct(k, Main.answer1) * usefullCoef - STARTPOINTY), 2, 2);
        g.drawOval((int) Math.round(k * usefullCoef) + STARTPOINTX, (int) Math.round((Main.frame.getContentPane().getHeight()) - Main.wayConstruct(k, Main.answer2) * usefullCoef - STARTPOINTY), 2, 2);
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте конкретики, а лучше работающий код и пример неудачных попыток.

Comment: Добавил код, не могли бы в общем виде сказать, что сделать надо. Не обязательно расписывать весь код.

Comment: Просто с кодом мне проще понять вас :) У вас есть компонент, на котором рисуются точки, это статическая картинка. Вы хотите сделать анимацию. Что является кадром анимации? Сделайте в своем компоненте поле "номер кадра", переделайте `paintComponent` для рисования произвольного кадра, потом по таймеру меняйте номер кадра и вызывайте `repaint()`. Как-то так.

Comment: Кажется сообразил, спасибо :)

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, оформите ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть компонент, на котором рисуются точки, это статическая картинка. Вы хотите сделать анимацию.

- Определитесь, что является кадром анимации (например, вы хотите постепенно показывать функцию для все больших максимальных значений x).
- Сделайте в своем компоненте поле "номер кадра" и переделайте `paintComponent` для рисования произвольного кадра. Либо вы можете запоминать момент начала анимации, и вычислять кадр в зависимости от прошедшего времени, подстраховавшись от неравномерной работы таймера.
- потом по таймеру меняйте номер кадра и вызывайте `repaint()`.

Comment: Решил, что создам просто два компонента. Сначала компонент который отрисует график, после отрисовки удалится и заменится на компонент со статическим графиком. Насколько это правильный подход?

Comment: А в чем будет разница?